# findpeaks with minimum distance in java

Tags: java, matlab, signal-processing

Has anyone tried to implement findpeaks function in matlab with minimum distance between them in java? or can you explain me the working of it. I was trying out the examples in matlab

a =

Columns 1 through 5

```
1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    1.0000    2.0000
```

Columns 6 through 10

```
3.0000    1.0000    1.0000    2.0000    0.1000
```

Columns 11 through 15

```
0.1000    0.1000    0.3000    0.2000    1.0000
```

Column 16

```
2.0000
```

> > findpeaks(a,'MINPEAKDISTANCE',2)

ans =

```
 3     3     2
```

How is this working?

Comment: try consulting the documentation, its pretty good.. http://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html

Comment: for further info, you may also check-out the Octave findpeaks.m source code, which is Free Software (GPL): http://sourceforge.net/p/octave/signal/ci/default/tree/inst/findpeaks.m